# Why is .sum() faster than .any() or .max()?

Tags: python, numpy

When optimising slow parts of my code, I was surprised by the fact that `A.sum()` is almost twice as fast as `A.max()`:

```
In [1]: A = arange(10*20*30*40).reshape(10, 20, 30, 40)

In [2]: %timeit A.max()
1000 loops, best of 3: 216 us per loop

In [3]: %timeit A.sum()
10000 loops, best of 3: 119 us per loop

In [4]: %timeit A.any()
1000 loops, best of 3: 217 us per loop
```

I had expected that `A.any()` would be much faster (it should need to check only one element!), followed by `A.max()`, and that `A.sum()` would be the slowest (`sum()` needs to add numbers and update a value every time, `max` needs to compare numbers every time and update sometimes, and I thought adding should be slower than comparing).  In fact, it's the opposite.  Why?

Comment: There is a related post about `any()`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17128116/why-is-numpy-any-so-slow-over-large-arrays?rq=1

Comment: I'm curious, why would you think `max` should be faster than `sum`? I could understand expecting both to be equally fast, or `sum` faster than `any`.

Comment: @delnan Because for `sum`, for every entry, it needs to (1) add two numbers (2) update a value, whereas for `max`, for every entry, it needs to (1) compare two numbers and (2) sometimes update a value.  I thought adding should be slower than comparing...

Comment: Conditional expressions are often slower than arithmetic ones because of the way CPUs are built : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9820319/why-is-a-cpu-branch-instruction-slow

Comment: @gerrit: Adding and comparing are typically the same speed, while _branching_ (required by max but not sum) is far, far slower. In particular, branch mispredictions might cost as much as 60 additions.

Comment: @gerrit Thanks for explaining. One reason that doesn't even pan out in theory (i.e. aside from branches being relatively slow in practice), is that "compare, if greater then ..." is *two* instructions, a comparisons and a conditional jump.

Comment: Related: [Why is processing a sorted array faster than an unsorted array?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11227809/why-is-processing-a-sorted-array-faster-than-an-unsorted-array).

Comment: Interesting, that doing the same timings on float data gives different results.

Comment: Oddly enough, I'm seeing the opposite of this on my machine. Max is marginally faster than sum. This is the same regardless of how the array is sorted. I'd bet that the speed difference here depends primarily on how NumPy is compiled and on the hardware you are using.

Comment: Hmm I just noticed that my test case was somewhat different from yours. I tried this on `np.arange(1000000, dtype=np.float64)`, `np.arange(99999, -1, -1, dtype=np.float64)`, `np.random.rand(1000000)`. When using the same test case, I get similar results, regardless of how the array is sorted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`max` has to store a value, *continuously checking* for potential updates (and the CPU needs to do branche operations to effect these). `sum` just churns through the values.

So `sum` will be quicker.

Comment: No. It's quicker because it doesn't have to branch. It's well known that modern processor perform much better when there are no failures in branch prediction. `sum()` completely avoid any branches and thus runs at full speed.

Comment: @Bakuriu try with a sorted list (no branch prediction failures) to check that claim

Comment: @wim Unless reshaping affects iteration order (which I doubt), the array in the question *is* sorted (in ascending order, specifically) as it comes out of `arange`.

Comment: Hmm, didn't notice that.  But how can we know `A.any` is implemented to traverse the array in the same direction as `A.flat`?