# FAST comparing two numpy arrays for equality [Python]

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, optimization, time

What is the FASTEST (not simplest) way to compare arrays?

Mostly i will have totally different arrays, that can be marked as unequal after checking the first element.

```
(a == b).all()              # first method
numpy.array_equal(a, b)     # second method
```

This two methods have similar time of execution, so something's not OK. **What is the method which terminates just after encountering first mismatch?**

---

This is NOT duplicate of this question:
[Comparing two numpy arrays for equality, element-wise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10580676/comparing-two-numpy-arrays-for-equality-element-wise)

Comment: And another: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45771554/why-isnt-numpy-any-lazy-short-circuiting

Comment: You can short-circuit by creating iterators `all(map(np.equal, a.flat, b.flat))`.

Comment: @PaulPanzer - that is actually extremely slow

Comment: You can make it significantly faster using the native `eq` instead of the numpy one. I was just too lazy to import it `from operator import eq`. And be sure to use the native `all`, too, not the `numpy` one. I quickly tested and for me it is faster for arrays of size `100` or so. Of course, if the arrays happen to be equal you may have a point ...