# Short circuit numpy logical_and on pandas series

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, short-circuiting

I create a mask to use in a pandas dataframe:

```
 mask = np.logical_and(
                csv_df['time'].map(operator.attrgetter('hour')).isin(
                    hours_set),
                csv_df['time'].map(lambda x: x.weekday_name[:3]).isin(
                    days_set))
csv_df = csv_df.loc[mask, :]
```

Turns out the calculation of the two `isin` Series is rather slow. The way above it calculates both Series and then adds them - is there an (idiomatic) way to short circuit per element, as the first series is mostly false so we won't need to calclulate the other series' element?

Comment: Related topic https://stackoverflow.com/q/45771554/901925

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One idea is:

```
mask = csv_df['time'].dt.hour.isin(hours_set) & 
       csv_df['time'].dt.strftime('%a').isin(days_set)
```

Anoather idea if most values not match is filter first one and then second:

```
csv_df1 = csv_df.loc[csv_df['time'].dt.strftime('%a').isin(days_set)]
csv_df2 = csv_df1.loc[csv_df1['time'].dt.hour.isin(hours_set)]
```

Comment: Thanks for the tricks - but this IIRC will still calculate both series due to python's eager evaluation of expressions

Comment: @Mr_and_Mrs_D - hmmm, I think i understand you, but not sure if supported in numpy/pandas it. Because need looking for different sets of values --- hours and days.

Comment: Nifty trick - since the first array will be calculated anyway