# Collapse mask array along axis - Numpy in Python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, mask, boolean-operations

I have a 2D array of masks that I want to collapse along axis 0 using logical OR operation for values that are `True`. I was wondering whether there was a numpy function to do this process. My code looks something like:

```
>>> all_masks
array([[False, False, False, ..., False, False, False],
       [False, False, False, ..., False, False, False],
       [False, False, False, ..., False, False, False],
       [False,  True, False, ..., False,  True, False],
       [False, False, False, ..., False, False, False],
       [False,  True, False, ..., False,  True, False]])

>>> all_masks.shape
(6, 870)

>>> output_mask
array([False, True, False, ..., False, True, False])

>>> output_mask.shape
(870,)
```

I have achieved `output_mask` this process through using a for loop. However I know using a for loop makes my code slower (and kinda messy) so I was wondering whether this process could be completed through a function of numpy or likewise?

Code for collapsing masks using for loop:

```
mask_out = np.zeros(all_masks.shape[1], dtype=bool)
for mask in all_masks:
    mask_out = mask_out | mask

return mask_out
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`ndarray.any`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.any.html):

```
all_masks = np.array([[False, False, False, False, False, False],
                      [False, False, False, False, False, False],
                      [False, False, False, False, False, False],
                      [False,  True, False, False,  True, False],
                      [False, False, False, False, False, False],
                      [False,  True, False, False,  True, False]])

all_masks.any(axis=0)
```

Output:

```
array([False,  True, False, False,  True, False])
```

Comment: @MaxCollier: Actually, I was wrong to claim that `np.any` short-circuits. It did at one point, but [currently, it does not](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45774536/190597).

Answer (score 3):

You could use `np.logical_or.reduce`:

```
In [200]: all_masks = np.array([[False, False, False, False, False, False],
       [False, False, False, False, False, False],
       [False, False, False, False, False, False],
       [False,  True, False, False,  True, False],
       [False, False, False, False, False, False],
       [False,  True, False, False,  True, False]])

In [201]: np.logical_or.reduce(all_masks, axis=0)
Out[207]: array([False,  True, False, False,  True, False])
```

[`np.logical_or`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.logical_or.html) is a [ufunc](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/ufuncs.html), and every ufunc has a [reduce method](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.reduce.html).