# Why "any" sometimes works much faster, and sometimes much slower than "max" on Boolean values in python?

Tags: python, pandas, performance

Consider the following code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
a = pd.DataFrame({'case': np.arange(10000) % 100,
                  'x': np.random.rand(10000) > 0.5})
%timeit any(a.x)
%timeit a.x.max()
%timeit a.groupby('case').x.transform(any)
%timeit a.groupby('case').x.transform(max)

13.2 µs ± 179 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
195 µs ± 811 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
25.9 ms ± 555 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
1.43 ms ± 13.1 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

b = pd.DataFrame({'x': np.random.rand(100) > 0.5})
%timeit any(b.x)
%timeit b.x.max()

13.1 µs ± 205 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
81.5 µs ± 1.81 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

We see that "any" works faster than "max" on a boolean pandas.Series of size 100 and 10000, but when we try to groupby and transform data in groups of 100, suddenly "max" is a lot faster than "any". Why?

Comment: In the transform one try `x.transform('any')` as a string. Otherwise it will use the python function. And as I know the vectorized ones do not short circuit.

Comment: It's called *"Short Circuit Evaluation"*, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `any` evaluation is lazy. Which means that the that the `any` function will stop at the first `True` boolean element.

The `max`, however, can't do so because it required to inspect every element in a sequence to be sure it haven't missed any greater element.

That's why, `max` always will inspect all element when `any` inspect only element before the first `True`.

The case when `max` works faster are probably the cases with type coercion because all values in numpy are stored in their own types and formats, mathematical operations may be faster that python's `any`.

Answer (score 0):

As said in comment, the python `any` fonction have a short circuit mechanism, when `np.any` 
have not. see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45771554/why-isnt-numpy-any-lazy-short-circuiting).

But `True in a.x` is even faster:

```
 %timeit any(a.x)
53.6 µs ± 543 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

%timeit True in (a.x)
3.39 µs ± 31.8 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```