# Is short-cut evaluation available for np.any()?

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, deep-learning, scipy

For example, I have a NumPy array:

`arr = np.array([1, 2, -1, 1, 2])`

and I want to say

```
np.any(arr<0)
```

How many elements will np check before returning ***True***?

(1) If short-cut evaluation is available, it should be 3, because as long as it sees "-1", it will return immediately return True.

(2) If short-cut evaluation is not available, it should check 5 times, because all elements would be checked.

Which one is correct?

Comment: Not sure why but my testing indicates there is no short circuiting. That's quite bizarre.

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45771554/why-numpy-any-has-no-short-circuit-mechanism

Comment: @cs95 so an array of 1e6 elements with a one in the beginning or end?

Comment: @MadPhysicist That's what I did, except I passed it to np.any as a bool array while timing it (to just time the circuiting, nothing else). PS tried this with version 1.19

Comment: @MarkMeyer. That's fascinating and fully answers this question, so I'm going to close as a dupe.