# Performance of numpy all/any vs testing a single element

Tags: python, numpy, performance, any

I create an array that does not contain a single zero (let's ignore that it does, with zero probability, as `np.random.rand()` samples [0,1) uniformly). I want to check whether all values are equal to zero (for some other purpose the arrays may contain all zeros). Below are some timings.

Surprisingly to me, checking a single (nonzero) element is about 2000 times faster than using `np.all()` or `np.any()`. I would assume that the compiler internally replaces `np.all()` by `np.any()` of the inverse condition and that `np.any()/np.all()` returns `True/False` at the first instance that the condition is fulfilled/violated (i.e. the compiler does **not** create the entire array of `True` or `False` values first).

How comes `np.all()` or `np.any()` are that much slower when it would only have to check one element? Or is this because of the external knowledge I put that the array does not contain all zeros? In the case of an all-zeros array, I guess it might be too slow to do the boolean comparison separately for each element. I don't know about the performance of the underlying low-level algorithms, but each element needs to be accessed once independent of whether it goes one by one or creates the whole boolean array once.

```
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(100)
a = np.random.rand(10418,144)
%timeit a[0,0] == 0
%timeit (a == 0).all()
%timeit np.all(a == 0)
%timeit (a != 0).any()
%timeit np.any(a != 0)

# 400 ns ± 2.08 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
# 713 µs ± 382 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
# 720 µs ± 1.17 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
# 711 µs ± 407 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
# 723 µs ± 630 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Comment: `np.all` and `np.any` are [not short-circuited](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45771554/why-numpy-any-has-no-short-circuit-mechanism). Also the timings include creating an intermediate array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you write `a == 0`, numpy creates a new array of type boolean, compares each element in `a` with 0 and stores the result in the array. This allocation, initialization, and subsequent deallocation is the reason for the high cost.

Note that you don't need the explicit `a == 0` in the first place. Integers that are zero always evauate to False, nonzero integers to True. `np.all(a)` is equivalent to `np.all(a != 0)`. So `np.all(a==0)` is equivalent to `not np.any(a)`